# How is this node.js module getting loaded?

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I have just started learning node and express and stumbled across this sample express application - https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo. 
The server.js file loads a module named config without a relative path -

```
var config = require('config')
```

https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo/blob/master/server.js#L15.
What I don't understand is how the module is getting loaded. There is no module named config in node_modules. The package.json contains NODE_PATH which points to `./config` folder. However, the config folder doesn't contain an `index.js` file. 
So how does the config object gets its properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NODE_PATH points to super-folders that contain Node modules (which may themselves be in folders, or maybe single files).

[The modules documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) says:

> If the `NODE_PATH` environment variable is set... then node will search those paths for modules if they are not found elsewhere.

It *search those paths for modules*; it does not treat those paths *as* modules.

Therefore, `require('config')` loads `./config/config.js`. The `NODE_PATH=./config:...` tells Node to look in `./config` for modules, and it find successfully finds a file called `config.js` in that folder, which it loads as a module.